# How to get scikit learn to find simple non-linear relationship

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have some data in a pandas dataframe (although pandas is not the point of this question).  As an experiment I made column ZR as column Z divided by column R.  As a first step  using scikit learn I wanted to see if I could predict ZR from the other columns (which should be possible as I just made it from R and Z).  My steps have been.

```
columns=['R','T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']
for c in columns:
    results[c] = preprocessing.scale(results[c]) 
results['ZR'] = preprocessing.scale(results['ZR'])
labels = results["ZR"].values
features = results[columns].values
#print labels
#print features
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(features, labels)
print(regr.coef_)
print np.mean((regr.predict(features)-labels)**2)
```

This gives

```
[ 0.36472515 -0.79579885 -0.16316067  0.67995378  0.59256197]
0.458552051342
```

1. The preprocessing seems wrong as it destroys the Z/R relationship I think. What's the right way to preprocess in this situation?
2. Is there some way to get near 100% accuracy? Linear regression is the wrong tool as the relationship is not-linear.
3. The five features are highly correlated in my data. Is non-negative least squares implemented in scikit learn ? ( I can see it mentioned in the mailing list but not the docs.) My aim would be to get as many coefficients set to zero as possible.

Answer (score 10):

You should easily be able to get a decent fit using [random forest regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html), without any preprocessing, since it is a nonlinear method:

```
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_features=2)
model.fit(features, labels)
```

You can play with the parameters to get better performance.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions is not as easy and can be very influenced by your data.

If your variables R and Z are bounded    `(for ex 0<R<1 -3<Z<2)` then you should be able to get a good estimation of the output variable using neural network.

Using neural network you should be able to estimate your output even without preprocessing the data and using all the variables as input.
(Of course here you will have to solve a minimization problem).

Sklearn do not implement neural network so you should use pybrain or fann.

If you want to preprocess the data in order to make the minimization problem easier you can try to extract the right features from the predictor matrix.

I do not think there are a lot of tools for non linear features selection. I would try to estimate the important variables from you dataset using in this order :
1-lasso
2- sparse PCA
3- decision tree (you can actually use them for features selection ) but I would avoid this as much as possible

If this is a toy problem I would sugges you to move towards something of more standard. 
You can find a lot of examples on google.

Comment: The variables are bounded and non-negative. They range up to a few hundred.  The data is real but my question is toy as clearly for this specific problem I can just use Z/R as the feature. My overall concern is how to find other simple multiplicative relationships in the data. I suppose I could just take logs?

Comment: if you define new variables as log(Z),log(R) and the output as log(Z/R) than you have a simple linear problem in the new variables. You can do this now because you know the real relation. In a real problem it would be much more difficult. I would suggest you to start with multiplicative relation. Define the output as Z*R instead and then move to neural network

Comment: You can probably be able to solve you original problem using radial basis function. They are a "more advanced" neural network. Anyway I think you should start with something of easier. For example you can try to estimate the function t*sin(t) using only one variable.